# Big Nerd Ranch Bronze Challenge: Disallow Alphabetic Characters

Tags: programming-challenge, validation, swift, cocoa

I just completed BNR's bronze challenge for disallowing alphabetic characters, and would love some feedback on what I did right and wrong, and how I can improve my code for reusability and maintainability.

Here's a snippet of instruction from their book, *iOS Programming: The Big Nerd Ranch Guide (5th Edition) (Big Nerd Ranch Guides)*:

> Currently, the user can enter alphabetic characters either by using a Bluetooth keyboard or by pasting copied text into the text field. Fix this issue. Hint: you will want to use the `NSCharacterSet` class.

I basically have a text field that takes numeric input. I allow the user to enter digits 0-9, inclusive with negative numbers and one decimal point. What the app does is convert Fahrenheit to Celsius, but that's not entirely relevant.

My `ViewController` is conforming to the `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol, and I'm implementing:

```
optional public func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool
```

Here's my snippet:

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    let existingTextHasDecimalSeparator = textField.text?.rangeOfString(".")
    let replacementTextHasDecimalSeparator = string.rangeOfString(".")

    if string.characters.count == 0 {
        return true
    }
    else {
        if let _ = string.rangeOfCharacterFromSet(NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "-0123456789.")) {
            if existingTextHasDecimalSeparator != nil && replacementTextHasDecimalSeparator != nil {
                return false
            }
            else {
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Two problems in your code**

You check if the replacement string contains *at least one* allowed
character, so that pasting  "1A" into the text field would be accepted.
Instead you should check if the string contains no invalid character:

```
if string.rangeOfCharacterFromSet(
    NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "-0123456789.").invertedSet) != nil {
    return false
}
```

(I prefer a comparison `!= nil` over an optional binding to the
unused variable `_` in this situation.) Note that this makes the initial
check for a non-empty string obsolete.

In order to prevent two decimal separators (such as "1.2.3"), you check if both
the existing string and the replacement string contain a period. But 
this prevents the replacement of – for example – "1.2" by "3.4" with
copy/paste. To handle that correctly, you have to build the
new string and check that:

```
if let existingString = textField.text as NSString? {
    let newString = existingString.stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)
    // check if `newString` contains more than one dot `.`
    // ...
}
```

**Possible improvements**

The decimal separator is not always the
dot character ".". In Germany for example (and many other countries),
floating point numbers are written as "12,34" with a *comma* as separator, and that would be denied with your code.

You *could* determine the correct localized decimal separator at
runtime:

```
let separator = NSNumberFormatter().decimalSeparator
```

and use that instead of the hard-coded period. But that still does not
cover all invalid input, such as "12-34-56".

There is a better (and simpler) solution: Check if the new string
after replacement can successfully be converted to a number, using
a `NSNumberFormatter`. That will recognize valid numbers according to
the user's locale correctly:

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    // Get current string as `NSString`
    guard let existingString = textField.text as NSString? else { return false }
    // Perform replacement:
    let newString = existingString.stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)
    // Check for empty result ...
    if newString.isEmpty {
        return true
    }
    // ... or valid number:
    let fmt = NSNumberFormatter()
    fmt.numberStyle = .DecimalStyle
    return fmt.numberFromString(newString) != nil
}
```

Since creating a number formatter is "expensive" (compare
[NSFormatter - NSHipster](http://nshipster.com/nsformatter/)), you
can improve that further by creating the formatter only once – for example as a static property.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `rangeOfString` to check if the strings contain a ".",
it will be more natural to use `containsString`.

```
let existingTextHasDecimalSeparator = textField.text?.containsString(".")
let replacementTextHasDecimalSeparator = string.containsString(".")
```

With this change, these variable names naturally make a lot more sense too.

---

Instead of `string.characters.count == 0`, a more idiomatic way to check if a string is empty using `isEmpty`, in this example `string.characters.isEmpty`.

---

Instead of this:

> ```
> if existingTextHasDecimalSeparator != nil && replacementTextHasDecimalSeparator != nil {
>     return false
> }
> else {
>     return true
> }
> ```

You can simply return the negated boolean expression, like this:

```
return !(existingTextHasDecimalSeparator != nil && replacementTextHasDecimalSeparator != nil)
```

Then go one step further and simplify using [De Morgan's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws):

```
return existingTextHasDecimalSeparator == nil || replacementTextHasDecimalSeparator == nil
```

---

When an `if` branch is guaranteed to return, you can eliminate the `else` branch, making the code more flat and slightly easier to read.

---

Putting the above suggestions together:

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    let existingTextHasDecimalSeparator = textField.text?.containsString(".")
    let replacementTextHasDecimalSeparator = string.containsString(".") 

    if string.characters.isEmpty {
        return true
    }
    if let _ = string.rangeOfCharacterFromSet(NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "-0123456789.")) {
        return !existingTextHasDecimalSeparator || !replacementTextHasDecimalSeparator
    }
    return false
}
```